# IE8 unstyled Menu list items

Tags: internet-explorer-8

I'm developing a front-end design which needs support for IE8+. When I open my prototype in VirtualBox (with IE8 from modern.ie) the list items from the Main Menu are not styled. At all.

Any idea why this is happening?

[VirtualBox screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JmjHo.png)

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BWGxbE

```
nav ul {
    display: inline;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 0 0 20px;
    max-width: 960px;
    list-style: none;
}

nav a {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 6px;
    margin: 0 6px;
    color: white;
}

    nav li {
        display: inline;
    }

    nav i {
        display: block;
        color: white;
        opacity: 0.6;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 20px;
        padding-bottom: 8px;
    }
```

p.s. first post, be gentle :)

Comment: Are you using the [HTML5-shiv](https://github.com/aFarkas/html5shiv) to ensure that unsupported elements can be styled in IE8?